# Using PHP to download multi files at one time

Tags: php

```
class Transfer {

/**
 * @access private
 * @var integer
 */
private $mDownStart;

/**
 * @access private
 * @var integer
 */
private $mFileSize;

/**
 * @access private
 * @var integer
 */
private $mFileHandle;

/**
 * @access private
 * @var string
 */
private $mFilePath;

/**
 * @access private
 * @var string
 */
private $mFileName;

/**
 * @access public
 * @return void
 **/
public function __construct() {
}

/**
 * @access public
 * @return void
 **/
public function Down($pFilePath, $pFileName = '') {
    $this->mFilePath = $pFilePath;
    if (!$this->iniFile())
        $this->sendError();
    $this->mFileName = empty($pFileName) ? $this->getFileName() : $pFileName;

    $this->iniFile();
    $this->setStart();
    $this->setHeader();

    $this->send();

    fclose($this->mFileHandle);
}

/**
 * @access private
 * @return boolean
 **/
private function iniFile() {
    if (!is_file($this->mFilePath))
        return false;
    $this->mFileHandle = fopen($this->mFilePath, 'rb');
    $this->mFileSize = filesize($this->mFilePath);
    return true;
}

/**
 * @access private
 * @return void
 **/
private function setStart() {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
        preg_match("/^bytes=([0-9]+)-$/i", $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], $match);
        $this->mDownStart = $match[1];
        fseek($this->mFileHandle, $this->mDownStart);
    } else {
        $this->mDownStart = 0;
    }
}

/**
 * @access private
 * @return void
 **/
private function setHeader() {
    @header("Cache-control: public");
    @header("Pragma: public");
    header("Content-Length: " . ($this->mFileSize - $this->mDownStart));
    if ($this->mDownStart > 0) {
        @header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
        header("Content-Range: bytes " . $this->mDownStart . "-" . ($this->mFileSize - 1) . "/" . $this->mFileSize);
    } else {
        header("Accept-Range: bytes");
    }
    @header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    @header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=" . $this->mFileName);
}

/**
 * @access private
 * @return string
 **/
private function getFileName() {
    return basename($this->mFilePath);
}

/**
 * @access private
 * @return void
 **/
private function send() {
    // fpassthru($this->mFileHandle);

    while (!feof($this->mFileHandle)) {
        set_time_limit(0);
        $buffer = fread($this->mFileHandle, 1024 * 1024);
        echo $buffer;
        flush();
        ob_flush();
    }
}

/**
 * @access public
 * @return void
 **/
public function sendError() {
    @header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    @header("Status: 404 Not Found");
    exit();
}
}
```

Here is how I use it,

```
 $transfer = new Transfer;
 $transfer->Down('D:\Pro lab\Aptana workspace\ezine\ezine\201202161811\VOL_001_201202161811.zip');
```

When i try to open two tabs of IE to run the script. But, They could not be downloaded at the same time. They are in the order of one after another.
But, When I put the file in the apache root directory. using still two tabs of IE to download them, they can be downloaded at the same time.
I wonder, Why it happens like that ?

I guess if there is any kind of "lock" in PHP, to limit the same client to download the same resource at same time ??

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess or other override that forces sessions to start in the subdirectory? If there is an active session, only one connection will work at a time - the other connections will block until the session is freed up.

Comment: I think, no active session here.

Comment: I suppose it is not a download thing, it's a PHP thing. To prevent too much load every session (and every call via http is a session) may execute just one script at the same time. Instead of passing the whole file through PHP you could write the file to a temp folder and make a redirect directly to this file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access the same script from two windows and the second script is locked, in most cases this is an indication of session locking.  Are you using sessions?  If so, you'll need to either:

1. Not use sessions - or -
2. Call `session_write_close` before starting the download as to release the session lock.

Note that any changes to the session after calling `session_write_close` are lost.

Comment: Ijust save the Transfer class in Transfer.php file. And visitor it through http://127.0.0.1/Transfer.php, I don,t use session here.